# Typescript typing issue on import JSON file

Tags: reactjs, json, typescript, react-redux

I am doing a migration to Typescript and struggling a little bit to find the right type for one of my JSON objects.

I am using a React hook inside my App to translate the content. The structure looks more or less like this:

**i18n/EN.json**

```
{
  "featured": "Featured",
  "replies": "Replies"
}
```

**i18n/DE.json**

```
{
  "featured": "Gekennzeichnet",
  "replies": "Antwortet"
}
```

**i18n/index.tsx**

```
import DE from './DE.json';
import EN from './EN.json';

export type i18nProps = {
  DE: { [key in keyof typeof DE]: string },
  EN: { [key in keyof typeof EN]: string },
};

const i18n: i18nProps = { DE, EN };

export default i18n;
```

**hooks/useTtranslate.tsx**

```
import { useAppSelector } from '.';
import i18n from '../i18n';

function useTranslate(): (key: string) => string {
  const lang = useAppSelector((state) => state.lang);

  return (key) => {
    return i18n[lang][key];
  };
}

export default useTranslate;
```

then in my React components, I use something like this:

```
const translate = useTranslate();
...
<div>
  {translate('featured')}
</div>
```

Definition of the lang state:

```
type LangType = 'EN' | 'DE';
export interface ForumState {
  ...
  lang: LangType,
}
```

But it seems that the typing of the hook and the i18n index file is not matching and I am getting the following error in the hook for the line:

```
    return i18n[lang][key];
```

Error:

```
Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type '{ "featured: string; replies: string; }'.
```

I guess the typing could be better in the `i18n/index.tsx` file and the `useTranslate.tsx` file?

Thanks a lot for any help here :)

Comment: where do you define `state.lang` ? Can you show us the type definitions of the state?

Comment: Hi @TobiasS. I added it on the post ;) Thanks

Comment: hmm interesting. When you hover over `lang`, does it say `string`?

Comment: TypeScript doesn't infer the types of imported JSON I'm pretty sure